# google Places search box & Fusion Tables queries

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Hi I'm trying to work out if i can use Google Place Search box and Fusion Table Layers together. I want the user to be able to select a layer from a drop down menu then search the street to see if it is inside boundaries of selected layer..

```
   <html>
    <head>
   <title>test ...</title>
   </head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#googft-mapCanvas {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 974px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var map_id = "13pxNPmnxbuV8xk82teyfHEm5KvSiKEeuBwBpu7KK"
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.462298859846875, 152.98324584960938),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "geometry",
        from: map_id,
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });
  }

  function selectChange(){
    var map_id = document.getElementById("map_no").value;
    //google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.462298859846875, 152.98324584960938),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "geometry",
        from: map_id,
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });
  };

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var textBlocks = new Array(  
"Brisbane Metro QPS", 
"QLD Main Roads",
"Council Boundaries",
"QLD Police Stations");
function changeText(elemid) {
var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex; 
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=textBlocks[ind]; 
}
</script>

<div style="width:974px; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<h2 style="padding:0px; margin:0px 0 0 0;">QLD INFORMATION</h2>
<select id="map_no" onchange="selectChange(); changeText('map_no');" style="width:600px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
  <option value="13pxNPmnxbuV8xk82teyfHEm5KvSiKEeuBwBpu7KK">Brisbane Metro Police</option>
  <option value="1GZ-SJfMiyXxoQgoebdQz0tknsuMmDLqBbUs9eOUN">QLD Main Roads</option>
  <option value="1g0ynAtTiolbrG547WpH8wPT1yYo3bjQnoWnd3UXJ">Council Boundaries</option>
  <option value="1y9C0dclTmEaERSRI3lQxiDHas2W2jBcs9w_jVs5R">QLD Police Stations</option>
</select>
  <div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>

<div id="display" style="margin-top:10px;">QLD</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

with this code from google places

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
 .controls {
 margin-top: 10px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 32px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 }

 #pac-input {
 background-color: #fff;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 300;
 margin-left: 12px;
 padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 width: 300px;
  }

 #pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
  }

  .pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
  }

  #type-selector {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #4d90fe;
 padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
  }

#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

    </style>
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]
}


    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

it should be easy but i'm new at this..
they work independently but together the search won't work
sorry for the long post, any help appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by "make the whole thing searchable"....you want to search for data in your FusionTable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I want to search streets just like Google maps, I've discovered how to use different layers. so if the user searches a street and wants to know the closest police station they would click the police station layer then type the street in search box here is my updated code..above

Comment: But your FusionTables only contain areas, not locations....a police station would be at a particular location.

Comment: I want it to zoom to the street searched for then use the layer to determine its local council, police etc. so if the user is doing work in that street for example they can find out the relevant departments for approval.. i have another layer for main roads. Is it possible to use google places Api as I can search streets with that code

Comment: To simplify I need to know if I can use the Places Search Box with select-able google Fusion Tables. The user can search a place or address and then be able to select different Tables from a drop down box. thanks